# WP7 ICommand and Navigation: its possible?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to use ICommand for navigation after executing of my command. my XAML:

```
                <ListBox Name="wordsManagerListBox" x:FieldModifier="private">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=originalWord}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu Name="WordManagerMenu">
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=R.CaptionEditWord, Source={StaticResource R}}" 
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

by default, in the command I can't to use NavigationService.Navigate. whether there are alternative ways to navigate? I think, that click handler in MyView.xaml.cs is no good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `NavigationService` via `Application.Current.RootVisual`, see [the following blog post](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2010/09/wp7-navigationservice-support-when.html) which uses this code:

```
    //magic code here!
    PhoneApplicationFrame root = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
    Debug.Assert(root != null, "Root is null");
    root.Navigate(address);
```